# Java Income Tax Calculator Need to add error message for any number that is 0 or less

Tags: java

I have a java project that is a Income tax calculator, and I am supposed to add a error message to it so that the program will not respond to a number that is 0 or less in the income prompt. I am just not sure where to put the prompt or what type of error message I need to accomplish this. Code:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class TaxCalculator {
    static void calculate() {
    // The tax rates for different types of customers.
    final double RATE1 = 0.20;
    final double RATE2 = 0.25;
    final double RATE3 = 0.10;
    final double RATE4 = 0.15;
    final double RATE5 = 0.30;
    final double RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT = 1;
    final double RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT = 1;
    final double RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 20000;
    final double RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 50000;
    double tax = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Prompt for user to enter the customers income
    System.out.print("Enter customer's income: ");
    double income = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
    String maritalStatus = in.next();
    in.nextLine();
    // Where the taxes are calculated
    if (maritalStatus.equals("s") && income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
        tax = RATE1 * income;
    } else if (maritalStatus.equals("m") && income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
        tax = RATE2 * income;
    } else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
        tax = RATE3 * income;
    } else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
        tax = RATE4 * income;
    } else {
        tax = RATE5 * income;
    }
    System.out.print("Your income tax is: $" + tax);
    }
    // asks user if they would like to process another customer.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String newResponse = "";
    do {
    calculate();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Process another response?. Please enter 'y' for yes, or 'n' for no: ");
    newResponse = in.next();
    in.nextLine();
    } while (newResponse.equals("y"));

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the loops after printing appropriate prompts:

```java
System.out.print("Enter customer's income: ");
double income;

while ((income = in.nextDouble()) <= 0) {
    System.out.print("Income " + income + " is invalid. Please input correct income which must be greater than 0: ");
    in.nextLine();
}

System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
String maritalStatus;

while (!(maritalStatus = in.next()).matches("[smc]")) {
    System.out.print("Marital status " + maritalStatus + " is invalid. Please input correct value: 's', 'm', or 'c': ");
    in.nextLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Enter customer's income: -12
Income -12.0 is invalid. Please input correct income which must be greater than 0: -23
Income -23.0 is invalid. Please input correct income which must be greater than 0: 2300
Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: 1
Marital status 1 is invalid. Please input correct value: 's', 'm', or 'c': m
```